# How to ConfigureAwait on custom awaitable class

Tags: c#, async-await, task, maui

I made an awaitable base class to use with `System.Windows.Input.ICommand` instances:

```
public class CommandContext
{
    private SemaphoreSlim _busy { get; } = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
    public TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter() =>
        _busy
        .WaitAsync()
        .GetAwaiter();
    public void Release()=>_busy.Release();
}
```

---

An `ICommand` might be defined as:

```
public ICommand InitDBPIsCommand { get; private set; }
// Return 'void' not 'Task' as this will only be invoked through `ICommand`.
private async void onInitDBPIs(CommandContext context)
{
    foreach (var dbpi in GetPrivsInUse())
    {
        await initDBPI(dbpi);
    }
    context.Release();
}
```

and instantiated as:

```
InitDBPIsCommand = new Command<CommandContext>(onInitDBPIs);
```

---

The goal of this, since almost everything that happens is `async`, is to have a usage where something like this is typical:

```
var context = new CommandContext();
Instance.InitDBPIsCommand?.Execute(context);
await context;
```

And this all works fantastic, I just would now like to be able to use `ConfigureAwait(true/false)` with this scheme and I can't quite figure out how to make that happen.

Comment: At what place would you like to apply this aspect? If it's at the time when the context is created, you can just pass it to ctor or prop and add ConfigureAwait to _busy.WaitAsync as it returns a Task. Note that you could also use TaskCompletionSource instead of SemaphoreSlim as you don't need a semaphore for what you're doing here.

Comment: I just want to do something like `await context.ConfigureAwait(false)` but I can't do that on `context` because it looks like a `TaskAwaiter` not a `Task`.

Comment: Looks complicated, i would add `Task ExecuteExclusively` extension to your `InitDBPIsCommand` type, which under the hood uses static SemaphorSlim. Then just call `await Instance.InitDBPIsCommand?.ExecuteExclusively();`

Comment: Note that the semaphore, at least in the example provided, is never taken, and only serves as a source of Task - the semaphore is initialized as count: 0, max: 1 and released in the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work for you?

Add this to your class

```
private bool _configureAwait = false;
```

Then provide a way to set that value, either through the constructor or a method.

```
public CommandContext(bool configureAwait)
{
    _configureAwait = configureAwait;
}
//or
public void SetConfigureAwait(bool value) => _configureAwait = value;
```

And in you method change that to

```
_busy.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(_configureAwait).GetAwaiter();
```

Then you can just do this

```
var context = new CommandContext(false);
// or
var context = new CommandContext();
context.SetConfigureAwait(false);
```

Then just use `await context;` normally

Comment: That's promising. It seems to work if the return type of `GetAwaiter` is changed from `TaskAwaiter` to  `ConfiguredTaskAwaiter` (which hadn't occurred to me) and invoked either of the ways you show. Holding out for `await context.ConfigureAwait(true/false)` but this would do in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a moment to see that the [answer by Mocas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77211995/5438626) does hold the key to solving this because implicitly it requires returning `ConfiguredTaskAwaiter`. I was stuck thinking I had to return "`Task` or something..." that could be configured when `CommandContext` itself *is the object that can be configured* and therefore needs to be the object that provides `ConfigureAwait()`. Once this is is addressed, classes that inherit `CommandContext` can be called either way, as `await context` or `await context.ConfigureAwait(false)` (for example when SQL queries aren't going to touch the UI).

```
public class CommandContext
{
    private SemaphoreSlim _busy { get; } = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
    public TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter() =>
        _busy
        .WaitAsync()
        .GetAwaiter();
    public ConfiguredTaskAwaitable ConfigureAwait(bool configureAwait)
    {
        return _busy.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(configureAwait);
    }
    public void Release()=>_busy.Release();
}
```

---

The syntax of an async database query that doesn't touch the UI looks pretty conventional now.

```
var context = new QueryDatabaseArrayCommandContext(
    target: PrivsInUse, 
    $"SELECT * FROM items WHERE tags LIKE '%{expr}%'");
QueryDatabaseArrayCommand?.Execute(context);
await context.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

---

Where:

```
QueryDatabaseArrayCommand = new Command<QueryDatabaseArrayCommandContext>(OnQueryDatabaseArray);
private async void OnQueryDatabaseArray(QueryDatabaseArrayCommandContext context)
{
    foreach (var database in context.Target)
    {
            context
            .Recordset
            .AddRange(await 
             new SQLiteAsyncConnection(database.LocalPath)
            .QueryAsync<Record>(context.SQL));
    }
    context.Release();
}
```

And:

```
class QueryDatabaseArrayCommandContext : CommandContext
{
    public QueryDatabaseArrayCommandContext(Database[] target, string sql) 
    {
        Target = target;
        SQL = sql;
    }
    public Database[] Target { get; }
    public string SQL { get; }
    public List<Record> Recordset { get; } = new List<Record>();
}
```

Comment: Nice. Please feel free to accept your answer if it is the better solution. I am glad I helped getting you there.

Comment: That's generous, thx! The 3+ upvotes and a check mark seem to indicate that you cracked the case. I just wanted to tie it in a bow and show the final product, but I think you deserve the credit.